# Vector Spaces and Polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

If I have functions f(x) = sin(x), q(x) = x^2+1 and s(x) = x^2+sin(x) which are linear combinations, how do I represent these functions as vectors? The sin(x) part is throwing me off when constructing the augmented matrix.

These functions are linear combinations of a vector space V of continuous functions. I want to find a basis of V. I don't understand how to construct the matrix in the appropriate way to find the basis vector.

Comment: They’re already vectors just as they are. Are you looking for their coordinates relative to some specific basis?

Comment: They already are vectors of the appropriate spaces, you should specify the ambient vector space. And a basis, since I assume you want coordinates.

Comment: They are linear combinations of *what*? What's the vector space that you are working with?

Comment: Hi, you can use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make math expressions more readable.  Please clarify your answer as per others' comments and tell use what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: These functions are linear combinations of a vector space V of continuous functions. I want to find a basis of V. I don't understand how to construct the matrix in the appropriate way to find the basis vector.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sorry, I clarified with my comment above.

Comment: The phrase “linear combinations of a vector space” doesn’t really make sense. Are you trying to say that the space that you’re interested in consists of all linear combinations of those three functions? If you’re looking for a basis for that space, first check whether or not those three functions are linearly independent. Don’t use a matrix to do that; use the fundamental definition of linear dependence/independence.

Answer (score 0):

These functions each live in the vector space of functions of the form $p(x)+c\sin x$ for polynomial-or-vanishing $p$ and constant $c$. For $f$ we take $p=0,\,c=1$; for $q$ we take $p=x^2+1,\,c=0$; for $s$ we take $p=x^2,\,c=1$. In fact, $f,\,q,\,s$ live in a smaller space spanned by $1,\,x^2,\,\sin x$. You can write them relative to this basis, or any other basis, including of course $f,\,q,\,s$ themselves. So, choose whatever basis suits you.